# Server-side only issue with AutoMapper/Managed ODP.NET

Tags: c#, oracle11g

I have a piece of code that uses AutoMapper and it works perfectly locally.  I use Managed ODP.NET for all my projects.  When I deploy to the server I'm getting an AutoMapper mapping error.

```
ATAL :: Mapping types: IDataRecord -> Debt System.Data.IDataRecord -> LetterSendingService.Service.Contracts.Debt 
        Destination path: Debt Source 
        value: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader
        Logger :: LetterSendingService.Service.Core.ErrorHandler 
        Thread :: 10 
        Date :: 2014-04-23 15:52:05,485 
        Dataset :: (null) 
        Parameters :: (null) 
        AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: 
            Mapping types: IDataRecord -> Debt System.Data.IDataRecord -> LetterSendingService.Service.Contracts.Debt
        Destination path: Debt
```

I initially thought it was related to decimals but its not.  My decimal handling code is as follows:

```
    public static decimal AsDecimal(this IDataRecord record, string parameterName)
    {
        if (record[parameterName] is OracleDecimal)
        {
            return ((OracleDecimal)(record[parameterName])).Value;
        }

        return Convert.ToDecimal(record[parameterName]);
    }
```

I appreciate that I need to change this code to pick up the field ordinal instead of using names for each index.

I've commented items out line by line.

Has anybody else experienced a similar problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: ATAL :: 

Mapping types:
IDataRecord -> Debt
System.Data.IDataRecord -> LetterSendingService.Service.Contracts.Debt

Destination path:
Debt

Source value:
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader
Logger :: LetterSendingService.Service.Core.ErrorHandler
Thread :: 10
Date :: 2014-04-23 15:52:05,485
Dataset :: (null)
Parameters :: (null)

AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: 

Mapping types:
IDataRecord -> Debt
System.Data.IDataRecord -> LetterSendingService.Service.Contracts.Debt

Destination path:
Debt

Comment: Sorry, don't yet know how to post code in comments.  'code' doesn't seem to work.  And working at 200mph trying to solve these problems and more.

Comment: If it works locally but not remotely then it's almost certainly an environmental issue - are your versions of .net, iis, database etc all the same on the two environments?

Comment: Hi Dave.  Yes I've checked Oracle, IIS and .NET versions and they are identical.

Comment: Is the data the same in the two oracle databases? Perhaps a specific piece of data is causing the problem?

Comment: Both the local code and the test deployment are hitting the same test database.  Its driving me mad!